MediaTek MT7902 WiFi not working on Ubuntu 24.04
I’m having trouble getting my MediaTek MT7902 WiFi card to work on Ubuntu 24.04 the last version of Ubuntu with kernel 6.8.0-51. The card works fine on Windows, but on Ubuntu, no networks are detected.
Details:

The card shows up in lspci:

00:02.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7902]

ip link output:

2: enx022376651f09: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 65536 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000

Firmware (linux-firmware) is up to date.

I loaded the mt76 driver (modprobe mt76), but it doesn’t seem to work.

dmesg gives:


read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
What I’ve tried:

Updated linux-firmware.
Loaded the mt76 module.
Restarted NetworkManager.
Unblocked WiFi using rfkill unblock all.

Question:
How can I get this WiFi card to work on Ubuntu? Do I need a specific driver, firmware, or kernel version?
Thanks for your help!

This exact WiFi card lacks a working driver.
The mt76 driver is only for these cards: MT76x0e, MT76x2e, MT7603, MT7615, MT7628 and MT7688
While on Windows it does work, on Ubuntu it WILL NOT work no matter what.

So there any way to work or not and are all Linux distributions not supported?

@KhaledAlrowaishan You can see for yourself: linux-hardware

Unfortunately it is not supported

At least we can sign a petition with hope
https://www.change.org/p/mediatek-should-provide-a-linux-driver-for-mt7902
